# Comparing two sets for new and missing keys

Tags: c#, dictionary, comparison, set

When comparing two key-value dictionary sets in C#: set A and set B, what is the best way to enumerate keys present in set A but missing from set B and vice-versa?

### For example:

```
A = { 1, 2, 5 }
B = { 2, 3, 5 }
```

Comparing B with A, missing keys = { 1 } and new keys = { 3 }.

Using `Dictionary<...,...>` objects, one can enumerating all values in B and test against set A using `A.ContainsKey(key);`, but it feels like there should be a better way that might involve a sorted set?

Comment: Likely has a trivial answer, but I'd like it to be performant for large sets or frequent changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm aware of two built-in ways of doing set differences.

1) [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

> Produces the set difference of two sequences by using the default equality comparer to compare values.

Example:

```
IEnumerable<int> a = new int[] { 1, 2, 5 };
IEnumerable<int> b = new int[] { 2, 3, 5 };

foreach (int x in a.Except(b))
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);  // prints "1"
}
```

2a) [HashSet<T>.ExceptWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875.aspx)

> Removes all elements in the specified collection from the current HashSet<T> object.

```
HashSet<int> a = new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 5 };
HashSet<int> b = new HashSet<int> { 2, 3, 5 };

a.ExceptWith(b);

foreach (int x in a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);  // prints "1"
}
```

2b) [HashSet<T>.SymmetricExceptWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336848.aspx)

> Modifies the current HashSet<T> object to contain only elements that are present either in that object or in the specified collection, but not both.

```
HashSet<int> a = new HashSet<int> { 1, 2, 5 };
HashSet<int> b = new HashSet<int> { 2, 3, 5 };

a.SymmetricExceptWith(b);

foreach (int x in a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);  // prints "1" and "3"
}
```

If you need something more performant, you'll probably need to roll your own collection type.

Comment: @Steve Guidi - how would you use HashSet<T> for key-value data?

Answer (score 2):

Use `SortedDictionary` : logic is `A.Except(A.Intersect(B))`.

Don't worry overmuch about performance until you've determined it is an issue to your datasets.

Comment: +1 easier to optimise a correct program than to correct an optimised program :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `Except` method.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "rabbit", "hat" }, { "frog", "pond" }, { "cat", "house" } };
Dictionary<string, string> dic2 = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "rabbit", "hat" }, { "dog", "house"}, {"cat", "garden"}};

    var uniqueKeys = dic1.Keys.Except(dic2.Keys);

    foreach (var item in uniqueKeys)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```

Comment: OP wants [`A\B`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory\)) and [`B\A`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory\)), or maybe [`A△B`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), but not [`A∩B`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory\)).

Answer (score 0):

So there are several answers here that will work. But your original question is best addressed in two parts:

Q) When comparing two key-value dictionary sets in C#: set A and set B, what is the best way to enumerate keys present in set A but missing from set B and vice-versa? Using Dictionary<...,...> objects, one can enumerating all values in B and test against set A using A.ContainsKey(key);, ...

If your starting with two dictionaries this may be the best approach. To do anything else would require creating a copy of the keys from both sets, thus making most alternatives more expensive.

Q) ...but it feels like there should be a better way that might involve a sorted set?

Yes this can be done with a sorted list easily enough. Create two List insertion sorted with BinarySearch, then walk set 1 while searching set 2 ect.

See this SetList Complement and Subtract operations:
http://csharptest.net/browse/src/Library/Collections/SetList.cs#234